# screen flickers after waking from blank screen

Tags: drivers, ati, screen, lock-screen, flicker

Every time I lock my screen and then unlock it again I get a really annoying screen flicker that stays until the next reboot.
It's not like a graphic glitch it's like the screen is refreshing at a wrong Hz rate. Any ideas for fixes?

Specs: Mobility Radeon HD5470 Graphic card with generic out of the box linux driver, Ubuntu 11.10 64-bit with the 3.0.0-15-generic kernel.

**I would like it if there's a solution not involving the ati proprietary drivers, because they have been nothing but trouble on my machine in the past.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend downloading the official ATI drivers and give it a try with them:

Download the newest ATI driver (current version is 12.1)

```
wget http://www2.ati.com/drivers/linux/amd-driver-installer-12-1-x86.x86_64.run
```

Once downloaded go to the file location and set it to run as executable

```
cd /path_of_the_file
chmod 755 amd-driver-installer-12-1-x86.x86_64.run
```

Use these steps to install

```
sh ./amd-driver-installer-12-1-x86.x86_64.run --buildpkg Ubuntu/oneiric
sudo dpkg -i fglrx*.deb
```

Once the driver is installed you need to start up a new xorg.conf file with this command

```
sudo aticonfig --initial -f
```

Reboot

```
sudo reboot
```

Comment: yeah I know...but that's what I would like to avoid. Are there any xorg settings I could fiddle with for example? since it's just a minor annoyance I'll live with it for now